# Synonym for "Passion driven"?

Tags: expressions, synonyms, vocabulary

What's a word for using one's motivation to accomplish something? I tried *passion driven* but it doesn't seem to fit. The sentence is:

> Motivation fosters the dedication needed to **____**.
>   or
>   Motivation fosters dedication needed to [be good at what you do]

If the question I've asked doesn't make sense, just complete the sentence that describes the importance of having motivation in a career.

Comment: *Motivation fosters dedication*? I had no idea motivation was so maternal.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the sentence in which you want to use this word? Leave a blank in the sentence. Currently it's not easy to see what you're asking. What doesn't help is that neither of your alternative sentences here are grammatical, but we can help with that if we know what you're actually looking for.

Comment: Isn't your whole sentence necessarily redundant? 'Where there's a will there's a way' traditionally links drive to resourcefulness.

Answer (score 1):

At first blush, the most natural word to complete the sentence

> Motivation fosters the dedication needed to `____`.

is ***succeed***, which accords well with the concept of "*to be good at what you do*".

Comment: There are loads of good synonyms for succeed in any thesaurus. I like *flourish*.